# std::map lower_bound is not returning the correct value

Tags: c++, linux, stl

Good afternoon, I am trying to use the std::map lower_found member function. However , it keeps returning the wrong answer. Here is an excerpt of my test code. Please explain to me how to make std::map lower bound function properly. Thank you.

```
class Interval { 
     public:   
         explicit Interval(int item){ 
            mLow = item;
            mHigh = item;
            mStamp = 0;
         }
         Interval(int low, int high, int stamp = 0){ 
            mLow = low;
            mHigh = high;
            mStamp = stamp;

         }
         Interval(void){  
            mLow = 0;
            mHigh = 0;
            mStamp = 0;

         }

         Interval(const Interval& r):
            mLow(r.mLow),
            mHigh(r.mHigh),
            mStamp(r.mStamp)
         {

         }

         bool operator<(const Interval& rhs) const{     
             if (mLow < rhs.mLow){             
                 return true;     
             }     
             return false;   
         } // operator<    
         int low() const { return mLow; }   
         int high() const { return mHigh; }
         int getStamp() const { return mStamp; }
         void setLow(int lower) { mLow = lower; }   
         void setHigh(int higher) { mHigh = higher; }
         void setStamp(int stamp) { mStamp = stamp; }
     private:   
         int mLow;   
         int mHigh; 
         int mStamp;
}; // class Interval 


 int main(int Argc_,char *Argv_[]) {
    int n;
    Interval r;

    std::map<Interval, Interval> Intervals_type;
    r.setLow(0);
    r.setHigh(10);
    r.setStamp(1);
    std::pair< Interval, Interval > tmp(r,r);
    Intervals_type.insert(tmp); 

    r.setLow(10);
    r.setHigh(20);
    r.setStamp(2);
    std::pair< Interval, Interval > tmp2(r,r);
    Intervals_type.insert(tmp2);    


    r.setLow(20);
    r.setHigh(30);
    r.setStamp(3);
    std::pair< Interval, Interval > tmp3(r,r);
    Intervals_type.insert(tmp3);    

    r.setLow(30);
    r.setHigh(40);
    r.setStamp(4);
    std::pair< Interval, Interval > tmp4(r,r);
    Intervals_type.insert(tmp4);    



    n = 36;
    std::map<Interval, Interval>::const_iterator it = 
               Intervals_type.lower_bound(Interval(n));
    if (it == Intervals_type.end()){
        printf(" n = %d not found\n",n);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it returns the wrong result? What do you expect? What does it return?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what result you expected, and what you actually got. I would expect it to print "not found" as 36 is larger than all the keys in the map, so lower_bound would return the end() iterator.

Comment: What does your program print, and what did you expect it to print?

Comment: @ybungalobill, I would like to return that n = 36 in found in the interval [30,40]. However, on Visual Studio it returns n = 36 not found. The same thing happens happens with std::map upper_bound. Thank you.

Comment: @Bo Person and @Rob Adams , When I do a linear search of the std::map I find  the 36 in interval [30,40]. I was hoping to find a faster way to search for the key. Could you please advise me as to the proper STL technique for speeding up std::map searches? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank Are you guaranteed that no ranges will overlap?

Comment: @Mark B , Thank you for your reply. I have to apologize for the fact that my ranges overlap. I will try my example with non-overlapping ranges. Thank you.

Comment: @Mark B. I changed my program to use non-overlapping ranges and i changed the compare member function. The program appears to work correctly. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you're dealing with ranges, and you have an invariant on
the map that ranges don't overlap.  If that's the case, you have
to define your operator< so that it deals with ranges, and does
something drastic (assertion failure or an exception) in the
case of an overlap, to prevent such ranges from being inserted.
Assuming a half open range of [low,high) and an assertion that
high >= low in the constructor of Interval, something like the
following should work:

```
struct CmpInterval
{
    //  For insertion...
    bool operator<( Interval const& lhs, Interval const& rhs) const
    {
        assert( lhs.low >= rhs.high
                || lhs.high <= rhs.low
                || (lhs.low == rhs.low && lhs.high == rhs.high) );
        return lhs.low < rhs.low;
    }
    //  For find, lower_bound, etc.
    bool operator<( Interval const& lhs, int target ) const
    {
        return lhs.low < target;
    }

    bool operator<( int target, Interval const& rhs ) const
    {
        return target <= rhs.high;
    }
};
```

The last two are used for lower_bound, find, etc., when you pass
a simple integer as key (and not an Interval); together, they
define a strict ordering relationship between an int and an
Inteval, *IFF* there are no overlapping intervals, and an
equivalence relationship such that all n in an interval [i, j) are
equivalent to that range and to each other.  (Again, if there
are overlapping intervals, there is no equivalence relationship,
and the behavior is undefined.)

Comment: I just accepted your answer. I will test it now, I remember reading your C++ posts over the last 7 years. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Frank You're welcome.  I had to solve a similar problem many, many years ago (when it was still C, before C with Classes even).  I've tried to adapt my solution to the std::map interface, but I've not tested anything, so good luck.  (Also, although it should be obvious: this type is an third template argument to map.)

Comment: Kanze,Is it possible to use a STL class (other than vector ) to handle duplicate intervals? I realize that that there is no equivalence relationship for duplicate intervals or overlapping intervals? Thank you.

Comment: Kanze, I retested ybungalobill's STD::multiset code and it handles duplicate intervals correctly. I apologize for the mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`std::map` compares with `operator <` only, so it knows only about `Interval::mLow`, effectively treating all intervals as [mLow, ∞). You're using the wrong container. It's possible to do it with map but it's harder. Use [Boost.Icl](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html) instead.

Edit: The best thing you have in STL for this purpose is std::multi_set. Order your intervals by the right end-point:

```
     bool operator<(const Interval& rhs) const{     
         return mHigh < rhs.mHigh;
     }
```

Now you can do it this way:

```
std::multi_set<Interval> cont;
cont.insert(Interval(0,10,1));
cont.insert(Interval(10,20,2));
cont.insert(Interval(20,30,3));
cont.insert(Interval(30,40,4));

std::multi_set<Interval>::const_iterator iter = cont.lower_bound(Interval(36));
if(iter == cont.end() || iter->low() > 36)
    // not found
else
    // found
```

Comment: @ybungalobill, I accepted your answer. What is the proper STL container to use? I believe STL uses balanced binary trees in std::set or std::map. I can't use Boost until we get the latest Solaris , IBM AIX and HPUX licenses. Thank you.

Comment: Nice one, I didn't remember there was something like this in Boost.

Comment: @Matthieu: It's a new library introduced in boost 1.46.0

Comment: @ybungalobill, I just read your edit. Thank you for figuring this problem.

Comment: @ybungalobill, I just tested the multi_set code which you suggested. It is better than std::hash approach I was trying. I noticed that the multi-set code may need to modified in order to search for duplicate keys or overlapping ranges. Thank you.

Comment: @ybungalobill, I retested your multiset code with duplicate ranges and it works correctly. I apologize for the mistake. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: that means that your test-cases are bad. It can't work correctly for overlapping ranges because linear ordering is not enough for that.

Comment: @ybungalobill, My test case is [0,10,1],[10,20,2],[10,20,3],[10,20,2] where std::multi_set<Interval>::const_iterator iter = cont.lower_bound(Interval(15));. The returned iterator does not equal cont.end() and iter->low() > 15 is not true. Is this a bad test case? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Frank: try [0,100], [20,80] and cont.lower_bound(Interval(10)). You will get that it's outside of any interval, but it's wrong.

Comment: @ybungalobill, Thank you for your reply. Test cases with overlapping ranges such [0,100],[20,80] will return an undefined result. However, in our application we can use you original solution since our application doesn't generate overlapping ranges. For the case of overlapping ranges, what is the best STL data structure? std::deque, std::vector or std::list? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

lower_bound should return the position before the first item that is equal or larger. The largest item in your map is actually smaller so end is returned.

In your operator < you only check mLow. If you want to check that 36 is in the range 30 to 40 then correct your operator <.

Comment: @Eelke, I accepted your answer. Should I check mHigh also. I tried checking mHigh and mLow before but the Microsoft STL implementataion checks operator < twice , once with the original argument and then it swaps the original argument with this. Thank you.

Comment: @Eelke, I just fixed the operator < to check mLow and mHigh,Now the program is running correct. I was wondering whether to continue using std::map or whether I should to switch to std::multi_set as ybungabobill suggested. Thank your for reply.

Comment: @Frank, set or multi_set would indeed be better storing everything two times serves no purpose. (set and map don't allow duplicates, multi_map and multi_set do)

Comment: @Eelke, Thank you for your help. I will try the multi_set solution suggested by ybungabobill.  James Kanze proposed an interesting solution for std::map.

Comment: @Eelke, I tested the multiset solution solution. It is a fine solution as long as we don't have duplicate ranges. I have an alternate solution albeit primitive for duplicate intervals. 1. Insert all the intervals into a std::vector or std::deque. 2. use quicksort to sort all the intervals. 3.Use binary search to find the target interval. Return the first target interval in the case of duplicate intervals. Thank you.

Comment: @Eelke, I retested the multiset solution. It handles duplicate intervals correctly. I apologize for the mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `lower_bound` is that it returns a location where you could insert the item and still keep the container sorted. Your comparison function only works with the `low` member; your container has the contents 0,10,20,30 for the lows. The only insertion point for 36 that keeps the container sorted is at the very end.

Comment: I just accepted your answer. Thank you for explaining how lower_bound is defined.